# Facebook: How to post on own page using graph api without login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-page

I own a blog like website, and as part of promotions I have a corresponding facebook page. My website contents are dynamic & when it gets updated(through a bot), I want the facebook page also to be updated by an automated post/publish from the bot which shows up the updates to the page viewers.

I could create a facebook page, and my bot programme which updates the web content is also able to publish the content on my facebook page using graph apis. But the posts are not publicly visible(Visible to only me/admin).

I could learn that it could be because my app through which my bot program is publishing to my facebook page is not public.

App->Status & Review, Status (Tab)
(Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?).

[image: Status & Review]

To make the app public, there is a review process which checks the facebook login button used in the website but my posts are through a backend bot and not through user action. My website is like a blog without user authentication so can't think of adding a login there.

Is it possible without having user login on the page? Also, If I post using twitter apis and link/configure my twitter account to my facebook page, it works.I guess this is not a new problem and many brands have automated it already, so need to understand how.

Am I missing something?

Apologies: I have checked previous posts on the same topic, but couldn't find relevant answers for the current Facebook version & policies.

Answer (score 0):

Without the [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) process, your posts can not be visible to the public.

To get it working, just send your page management tool (with the login dialog) for the review. Once they review it and accepted, you may change the flow a bit eg: skip the login part and allow auto posting.